# Unable to get data in human readable format from private data collection using node sdk

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

So I am trying to explore private data collection and I have written the chaincode in javascript. I am passing the proper collections file while instantiating the chaincode and while invoking the chaincode I am adding the transient data in request payload which looks like this :

```
const proposal_request = {
  chaincodeId: chaincodeId,
  fcn: functionName,
  args: args,
  chainId: channelCode,
  txId: tx_id,
  transientMap : { "private" : "test data"}
};
```

My chaincode file looks like this :

```
const shim = require('fabric-shim');
const util = require('util');

var PrivateDataChaincode = class {

 // Initialize the chaincode
 async Init(stub) {
  console.log('<================> ::Private Data Chaincode Instantion:: <=================>');
  return shim.success();
 }

 async Invoke(stub) {
  console.log('<================> ::Private Data Chaincode Invocation:: <=================>');
  let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
  console.info(ret);
  let method = this[ret.fcn];
  console.info('methodName');
  console.info(method);

  if (!method) {
   console.error('No method of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found');
   return shim.error('No method of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found. \n UNKNOWN FUNCTION INVOCATION: ' + ret.fcn);
  }
  console.info('\nCalling method : ' + ret.fcn);
  try {
   let payload = await method(stub, ret.params);
   return shim.success(payload);
  } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
   return shim.error(err);
  }
 }

 async createPrivateDataInCollection(stub, args) {
  if (args.length != 2) {
   throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2');
  }

  // arg[0] has the collection name
  // arg[1] has the key

  console.info("============= START : Create Private data ===========");
  // get the transient map
  let transientData = stub.getTransient();
  await stub.putPrivateData(args[0], args[1], transientData.map.private.value);
  console.info('============= END : Create private data ===========');
 }

 async queryPrivateDataInCollection(stub, args) {
  console.info('============= START : Query private Data ===========');
  // arg[0] has the collection name
  // arg[1] has the key
  // query private data with argument
  let allResults = await stub.getPrivateData(args[0], args[1]);
  if (!allResults) {
   throw shim.error("Can't get data from state");
  }
  console.log(allResults);
  return allResults;
 }
};

shim.start(new PrivateDataChaincode());
```

I am storing data using createPrivateDataInCollection method and fetching the data using queryPrivateDataInCollection. Apparently, the data is converted to some Buffer implicitily before it gets inserted and I am having trouble to convert this data back to readable format when it is read. Any idea how to convert the data to a readable format?

When I tried to print the value of transientData.map.private.value that I am storing, I got this :

```
ByteBuffer {
  buffer: <Buffer 0a e7 07 0a 97 01 08 03 10 01 1a 0b 08 8b f8 d3 f6 05 10 c0 d3 b4 16 22 0d 74 72 61 64 65 2d 63 68 61 6e 6e 65 6c 2a 40 39 36 35 34 61 36 31 39 63 30 ... >,
  offset: 1126,
  markedOffset: -1,
  limit: 1147,
  littleEndian: true,
  noAssert: false }
```

And when I print the result in queryPrivateDataInCollection, I get this :

```
<Buffer b5 eb 2d b6 18 ac 8a ca 6b 8a f6 ad 79 d6 ad 6a d7 ac b7 68 62>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your buffer data to string using toString method.

`transientData.map.private.value.buffer.toString();`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I tried this and was able to get the data, the caveat being there was some additional info that came along with it. So I just extracted the required data out of it